# Tensorflow neural network perform bad on test data but has high accuracy on validation set

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have preprocessed a dataset in the following way:

```
train, test = train_test_split(deep_df, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.3)
```

The training dataset has the following column: id, J, H, K, B, C, D, E, F, G, I, DAY, WEEK_DAY, HOUR, A, install (target).

```
# numerical features
num_f = ['A'] 
num_f_bucket = ['B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G'] #bucketsize
# categorical features
cat_f_enc = ['H','I'] #encoding
cat_f_emb = ['J','K'] #embedding

# function to get scale the numeric value
def get_scal(feature):
    def minmax(x):
        min_value = train[feature].min()
        max_value = train[feature].max()
        return (x - min_value)/(max_value-min_value)
    return(minmax)

feature_columns = []

# scale numerical feature
for i in num_f:
    stand_f = get_scal(i)
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(i, normalizer_fn=stand_f))
    
for j in num_f_bucket:
    stand_d = get_scal(j)
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(j, normalizer_fn=stand_d))

# bucket numerical feature

B_count = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("B")
B_bucket = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(B_count, boundaries=[0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1])
feature_columns.append(B_bucket)

C_count = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("C")
C_bucket = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(C_count, boundaries=[0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1])
feature_columns.append(C_bucket)

D_count = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("D")
D_bucket = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(D_count, boundaries=[0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1])
feature_columns.append(D_bucket)

E_count = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("E")
E_bucket = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(E_count, boundaries=[0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1])
feature_columns.append(E_bucket)

F_count = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("F")
F_bucket = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(F_count, boundaries=[0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1])
feature_columns.append(F_bucket)

G_count = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("G")
G_bucket = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(G_count, boundaries=[0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1])
feature_columns.append(G_bucket)

# encoding columns
for f in cat_f_enc:
    vocabulary = deep_df[f].unique()
    cat_enc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(f, vocabulary)
    one_hot_enc = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(cat_enc)
    feature_columns.append(one_hot_enc)

# embedding columns
for f2 in cat_f_emb:
    vocabulary = deep_df[f2].unique()
    cat_emb = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(f2, vocabulary)
    embeding = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(cat_emb, dimension = 10, combiner='sqrtn')
    feature_columns.append(embeding)
```

And built an NN model as follow:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
optim2 = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001)
metrics = ["accuracy"]

model.compile(optimizer=optim2,
              loss=loss,
              metrics=metrics)

batch_size = 32
epoch = 15
history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epoch, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

Which produces an accuracy of 0.8956249952316284 on the test_ds.

I have tried to apply the model on a unseen data but the model is performing badly since there is no probability that can be classified as 1.

```
predicted_ar=model.predict(test_predict)

{'id': {94616: '5c45a8ca7014dc0cff03d95b',
  136837: '5c364dfe9a9bbc29790789c7',
  392434: '5c40fde5af1f4d3d50b20f2c',
  50517: '5c3e6d960dfa21e9a661eac3',
  18854: '5c42058a3f08eb16205ae23a'},
 'install': {94616: 0.24374890327453613,
  136837: 0.07109987735748291,
  392434: 0.18612107634544373,
  50517: 0.22151124477386475,
  18854: 0.23157894611358643}}
```

I know I have not provided any sample of the data, but do you have any suggestions on how to improve my prediction? I am missing something? The thing I am not sure is if the test_predict is automatically preprocessed as the training or not.

In case it might help this are the learning curve

[image: learning curve of the model]

Answer (score 1):

Some things that might help are:

- Checking the distribution in your datasets, if you have a very unbalanced dataset this may lead to a misleading accuracy;
- You can try shuffling the datasets, in case they are ordered in a way were you got some cases concentrated in the test dataset;
- If you need probability closer to one in you output (or you are doing a multiclass classification task), try switching your output activation function to from sigmoid to softmax.